# Retrieve data from Android HTTP Post

Tags: java, android, servlets

I have been looking at several other posts and what I'm trying to do is that retrieve the object over request with Android which is set.

I'm using google gcm application.

***My Android the code is*** :

```
DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();
HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.111:8080/abc/d");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("My_Value", "My_Value_entered"));  
postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
String response=hc.execute(postMethod,res);
```

I want to fetch the the value My_value in my Application(in the servlet end).

Edit: If any change or modification is needed in my android code to get the object value from Android Post,feel free to reply.

Any idea.....

Comment: This is a servlet question, not Android. The Android part is pretty vanilla - forming a urlencoded POST form.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `jsoup` which is much easier to use. You can check it at [jsoup.org](http://jsoup.org)

edit:

like this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www......com/....php")
                .data("user","user","password","12345","email","info@tutorialswindow.com")
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute()
                .parse();
```